# How to integrate ACE editor into Qooxdoo build?

Tags: javascript, qooxdoo

I mangaged to get the ACE editor (http://ace.ajax.org/) working with my qooxdoo project by dropping the required .js and .css files in the resource directory and requiring them with an #asset(...) directive in the sources.

While this is working fine, it just doesn't feel right. Is there a chance to integrate ACE in a way that lets the qooxdoo build scripts integrate it in the big resulting JS and CSS files?

Answer (score 2):

It's an ok way to do it. As for the single build script, you would need to wrap the ACE code into qooxdoo classes to achieve that. In general, it's much better to leave external libraries on their own, because the generator can treat qooxdoo code in ways that are not possible for arbitrary JS code, part. concerning linking.

And for qooxdoo apps there are usually no CSS files.